# What CSI does raspberry pi Zero W has

Tags: dsi

I am trying to find a replaceable part for CSI connector on Raspberry pi Zero W since I broke it. (I am buying the full connector and will just use the black part I broke, I will not re-solder anything).

[image: Broken connector]

What CSI is it? Looking at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_Serial_Interface) I can see there are CSI-1, 2 and 3, but I do not know which is for my raspberry pi Zero W, since there are no pictures on how each one looks like, or even how many pins it has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find that you have to buy the whole connector.  Adafruit sells a spare (as of March 2021) but its not for the zero but the larger ones on the other Pi boards :-(

The part you need is from Molex part number 54548-2271 and it's a right angle 22 pin 0.5mm pitch connector.

A list of the connectors can be found on [the ArduCam](https://www.arducam.com/raspberry-pi-camera/connector-type-pinout/) website with pin outs if needed.

As shopping requests are discouraged here I'll leave it you to source :-)

Comment: Oh i see, you are right. Just to add to your answer, it was on FFC & FPC Connectors in Mouser. For some reason I vould not find that easily.